# QTableWidget возвращается на первую строку при клике в любую ячейку

Tags: pyside2

у меня есть QTableWidget с одним столбцом и множеством строк. В каждую из строк установлены  QGroupBox с кнопками, соединяющимися с функцией сигналом по клику.

При клике на кнопку в любой строке меня выбрасывает обратно на первую строку в начало. Как этого избежать, чтобы таблица не возвращалась наверх? Даже если функция выглядит так:

```
print('clicked')
```

При клике кнопку меня возвращает в начало таблицы. Проблема есть только на Windows.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких попыток проблема решилась простой командой:

```
self.table.setAutoScroll(False)
```